# Node.js Express - next() callbacks

Tags: node.js, express

In Node.js Express - using app.use functions-

why don't I have to do this:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    //do something here
    next(req,res);
});
```

usually I just do this and it works

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    //do something here
    next();
});
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`next()` already knows the `req` and `res` for the currently executing request, thus you just call it directly.  It is a unique function created just for this request.  It also keeps track of where you currently are in the middleware stack such that calling `next()` executes the next middleware in the chain.

If you look at the [express source code for the router](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L122), you can actually see the locally defined `next()` function and can see how it has access to a bunch of closure-defined variables that include `req`, `res` and index counter that it uses for advancing through the middleware stack and a bunch of other variables.  Thus, it already has access to everything it needs to launch the next middleware call so there is no reason to pass it those things.

FYI, one of the great things about using open source is that you can always just go look at the code yourself and see what it does.

When invoking `next()`, you have several choices:

1. You can invoke it as `next()` and this will just invoke the next middleware handler in the stack.
2. You can invoke it as `next('route')` and it will skip to the next route handler.
3. You can pass an error `next(err)` and stop all further middleware or router handling except for error handlers.

The details are documented here: http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html.

Here's a note from that page:

> `next()` and `next(err)` are analogous to `Promise.resolve()` and
>   `Promise.reject()`. They allow you to signal to Express that this
>   current handler is complete and in what state. `next(err)` will skip all
>   remaining handlers in the chain except for those that are set up to
>   handle errors as described in the next section.

Comment: This is only partially correct given there is no mention of passing an `Error` to `next`. This allows you to bypass all future pieces of middleware in the stack, directly calling the final error handlers.

Comment: @ded - I will work on adding that to my answer, but you downvoted me for leaving out something that was not even part of the question and not even something the OP intended to ask about?  Seriously?

Comment: I'll undo the downvote :) I didn't intend derail your answer and want to keep things friendly. My assumption is that the original question includes a code block passing `next(req,res);` -- it would probably be a good answer if you included what is appropriate to to pass to `next`.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `next` accepts an optional `Error` object. if you pass nothing to it, it assumes you're ready to continue onto the next piece of middleware or your actual mounted handler. **Otherwise**, if you pass an instance of an `Error` object, you'll bypass your mounted handler (and sequential middleware) and go directly to the error handler.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user || !req.user.isAuthorized) next(Error('not allowed'))
  else next()
})

app.get('/:user', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('users/index', { user: req.user })
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err.message) // not allowed
  res.render('500', err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand the internal working by looking in the sources provided by jfriend00, but didn't wanted to loose too much time trying to isolate the specific part which handles the callbacks.

So I tried my own:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85rLhc62/3/)

```
function MW(req, res){
    var req1 = req, res1 = res;
    Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
    Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
    var MWs = arguments;
    console.log(MWs, req1, res1);
    function handle(index){
        if(index ===MWs.length-1){
            return ()=>{MWs[index](req1, res1, ()=>{})};
        }
        return ()=>{MWs[index](req1, res1, handle(index+1))};
    }
    var next = handle(0);
    next();
}
```

Basically, it uses recursion to build the chain of callbacks.

You can then use it as `Express use/get/post/put/...`:

```
MW(req, res, 
    (req, res, next)=>{
        console.log("first");
        req.locals = {
            token : 'ok'
        };
        res.canSend =false;
        next();
    },
    (req, res, next)=>{
        console.log("second");
        console.log(req.locals.token, res.canSend);
        next();
    }
);
```